# How to submit SOAP request in The Grinder

Tags: soap, jython, grinder

The grinder uses jython as it's primary scripting language.

I need to test some web services that only have soap interfaces.

I have not been able to find a way to get this to work.  I'm new to The Grinder, and although they have a sample script showing use of XmlRpcClient, even this example errors out stating "Import Error: No module named apache"

Comment: Sounds like your classpath or pythonpath is not set up correctly.  Perhaps you could include your jython code and the log output containing the error message?

Answer (score 2):

here is sample code for my web service:

```
# coding=utf-8

import traceback
from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder
from net.grinder.script import Test
from net.grinder.plugin.http import HTTPPluginControl, HTTPRequest
from HTTPClient import NVPair

connectionDefaults = HTTPPluginControl.getConnectionDefaults()
httpUtilities = HTTPPluginControl.getHTTPUtilities()
connectionDefaults.useContentEncoding = 1
log = grinder.logger.info

class TestRunner:

    def __call__(self):
        your_url_for_web_service = ''
        your_soap_message_body = ''
        soapMessage = """<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>"""+
    your_soap_message_body+"""
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"""
        self.send_service( your_url_for_web_service, soapMessage )

    def send_service( self, soapMessage ):                
        request = HTTPRequest()
        headers =   (
                    NVPair( "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" ),
                    NVPair( "Content-Length", str( len( soapMessage ) ) ),
                    )
        request.setHeaders(headers)
        httpResponseObject = request.POST( url, soapMessage )
        soapAsString = httpResponseObject.getText()
        log( soapAsString )

def instrumentMethod(test, method_name, c=TestRunner):
  """Instrument a method with the given Test."""
  unadorned = getattr(c, method_name)
  import new
  method = new.instancemethod(test.wrap(unadorned), None, c)
  setattr(c, method_name, method)


# Replace each method with an instrumented version.
instrumentMethod(Test(1, 'soap request showcase example'), 'send_service')
```

Be sure to change the following in the `call` method:

```
your_url_for_web_service = ''
your_soap_message_body = ''
```

with appropriate values for your web service.

Comment: @user912563 What issues have you encountered? I put on purpose my version of getting the body of soap response. My solution works when you use two byte encoded utf-8 characters. For example šđčćž. Using just getText() does not work for soapResponse that contains those characters.